# Python: find a method to calculate the “inner centroid” (also known as labelPoint in arcmap) of a polygon

Tags: python, geometry, algorithm

I am looking for a method to compute the X,Y coordinate of an inner point (also known as labelPoint in arcmap) of a (irregular) polygon. I try to find a solution without the use of ArcGIS module.

[image]

The difference between a "centroid" and a labelPoint is that the centroid may be outside the polygon.

I am using [shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) module from shapely.geometry import Polygon:

```
ref_polygon = Polygon(points)
# get the x and y coordinate of the centroid
ref_polygon.centroid.wkt
'POINT (558768.9293489187300000 6361851.0362532493000000)'
```

using the following data (the vertex of my polygon):

```
points = [(560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560036.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560036.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560037.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560037.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362064.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560035.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560035.4495758876, 6362062.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362062.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560032.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560032.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560030.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560030.4495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560029.9495758876, 6362061.390493258),
          (560029.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560029.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560029.4495758876, 6362059.890493258),
          (560028.9495758876, 6362059.890493258),
          (560028.9495758876, 6362059.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362059.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362058.890493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362058.390493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362058.390493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362057.890493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362057.890493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
          (560023.4495758876, 6362057.390493258),
          (560023.4495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560023.9495758876, 6362060.390493258),
          (560023.9495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560024.4495758876, 6362061.890493258),
          (560024.4495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560024.9495758876, 6362063.390493258),
          (560024.9495758876, 6362064.390493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362064.390493258),
          (560025.4495758876, 6362065.390493258),
          (560025.9495758876, 6362065.390493258),
          (560025.9495758876, 6362065.890493258),
          (560026.4495758876, 6362065.890493258),
          (560026.4495758876, 6362066.890493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362066.890493258),
          (560026.9495758876, 6362068.390493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362068.390493258),
          (560027.4495758876, 6362068.890493258),
          (560027.9495758876, 6362068.890493258),
          (560027.9495758876, 6362069.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362069.390493258),
          (560028.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
          (560033.4495758876, 6362069.890493258),
          (560033.4495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560033.9495758876, 6362070.390493258),
          (560033.9495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560034.4495758876, 6362070.890493258),
          (560034.4495758876, 6362071.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362071.390493258),
          (560034.9495758876, 6362071.890493258),
          (560036.4495758876, 6362071.890493258)]
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the representative point is what you are looking for

http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#object.representative_point

Essentially, you would just use ref_polygon.representative_point().wkt instead of the centroid method.

Edited to provide real example.

Comment: +1, I suspect Gianni began with an Arc-centric background as ESRI does in fact refer to this as `labelPoint` in their system. I'm happy to learn there is a synonym for this in other technologies and APIs.